# Possibly something wrong with my terminal

Tags: command-line, alias

Whenever I open my terminal I get something like this:

```
 alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias l='ls -CF'
    alias la='ls -A'
    alias ll='ls -alF'
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
```

I'm not sure what this is or what it means I'm new to Linux.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the output of `cat ~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 2):

This is the output of the `alias` command which shows you all the aliases defined on your shell. (For more info about it, type `man alias`; alias is explained under "Bash Builtin Commands").

It means that somewhere in your `.bashrc` file you have this line:

```
alias
```

Remove it and you'll be good to go.

Comment: I may be blind but I don't see a line that just as the word alias.

Comment: @lwilkovich This behavior is exactly what `alias` command ran with no arguments, dr01 is right. Try this :  `awk '/^alias/{if ($2 == "") print NR}' ~/.bashrc      ` This should tell you line number with the `alias`  being the only item there

Comment: Please add the output of `cat ~/.bashrc` to your question, as asked by @heemayl . It is possible that the alias command is hidden amongst other commands.